# Problems exporting class for shared library on Android

Tags: android, c++, c, arm, gnu

I have a core project which I'm building as a shared library.  In one of the headers, I've defined a simple class shown below:

```
typedef pthread_mutex_t Mutex;

class CORE_API AutoLock
{
public:
    AutoLock(Mutex& m);
    ~AutoLock();

private:
    AutoLock();
    AutoLock(const AutoLock&);
    AutoLock& operator=(const AutoLock&);

    Mutex m_Mutex;
};
```

where CORE_API is defined as:

```
#ifdef CORE_DLL
#define CORE_API    __attribute__ ((dllexport))
#else
#define CORE_API    __attribute__ ((dllimport))
#endif
```

In the Android.mk for core, I've defined CORE_DLL under LOCAL_CFLAGS.  However, when building, I get the warning:

```
warning: 'dllimporot' attribute directive ignored
```

When ndk-build gets to the other project where I want to use the AutoLock class, I get the error:

```
error: 'AutoLock::AutoLock()' is private
error: within this context
```

Why would the compiler ignore the dllexport attribute?  I would hope that once that's fixed, my other project should build and be able to use the AutoLock class without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared libraries are created differently on Android (Linux) than with Windows.
In Windows you have the special dllimport and dllexport directives but not on Android (Linux).

When using your shared library, you should just compile with -lYourLibraryName

This might help you: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html

Comment: I've tried adding: -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/armeabi -lcore to my Android.mk file but unfortunately I still get the 'AutoLock::AutoLock()' is private error.

Comment: The solution I gave you has nothing to do with that error. It only deals with the error you have on dllimport and dllexport. The AutoLock error is pretty self explanatory... If you want to construct an object that way move the AuthLock() constructor into public scope

Comment: That's interesting; I just realized the error message is referencing the default constructor, but that's not used anywhere.  I've left that private and undefined intentionally as I only wanted AutoLocks used with a Mutex passed to it.  The line the error refers to is this: AutoLock(m_CommandMutex);  So I'm not sure why it's complaining about the default being private.  Making it public and defining it gets rid of that error.

Comment: Then it's being used somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the sample code available in the android-ndk, specially the Android.mk file this might solve your problem.